# How to add some characters to filename via 'rename'?

Tags: linux, files, rename

For example I have a file named `5.jpg`.  How can I rename it to `aaaaa.jpg` with char `a` 5 times.

I tried `rename -v 's/(\d{1,})/a{$1}/g' *` but this renames `5.jpg` to `a{5}.jpg`, which is not what I want. I understand that second part of function isn't a regexp, this was just an attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least three different utilities imaginatively named `rename(1)` are floating around in the Linux waters: (1) the one that came with `util-linux`, (2) an older Perl script by Larry Wall further munged by Tom Christiansen, and (3) a newer Perl script evolved from the former and included with `Unicode::Tussle`.  As far as I can tell, what you want can't be done with the `util-linux` version of `rename(1)`.  It can be done with either of the Perl scripts though:

```
rename -n 's/(\d+)/"a" x $1/e' 5.jpg
```

Output:

```
rename 5.jpg aaaaa.jpg
```

(drop the `-n` to actually rename the file).

Comment: Hadn't realised there were (at least) three alternatives. I knew of two - a perl one and what I assume must be the util-linux version

Comment: Oh yeah, that's what I want! Thanks a lot, will search for more info

Comment: @roaima It came up in a previous SO thread: I posted an answer using the syntax of my `rename(1)` from `Unicode::Tussle`, and somebody complained some options were not recognized on his version.  As it turned out he was using a different `rename(1)` (an older script munged by the Debian guys, I think).  Amazingly, none of the authors thought that `rename` is actually a really common name and that it would be wise to call it something else instead.

Answer (score 2):

If (and this is a big if) you are using the `rename` that uses a `perl` expression to modify filenames you can achieve what I think you want like this:

```
rename 's/(\d+)/"a" x $1/e' *
```

The `e` flag is explained in `perldoc perlre`. It modifies the interpretation of right hand side so that it is evaluated as a perl expresssion.

Comment: Just like previous answer, yup. But what is '/e' ?

Comment: @Antipers007 yes, we wrote our answers pretty much simultaneously. I've updated my question to explain `e`.