# What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?

Tags: debian, perl, rename

On my Debian system (well, my LMDE system, but close enough), I have at least 3 different `rename` programs:

- `/usr/local/bin/rename` : This is a Perl script, written by Tom Christiansen. Oddly enough, I can't seem to find which package installed it:

  ```
  $ dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/rename 
  dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/rename
  ```
- `/usr/bin/prename` : another perl script, written by Robin Barker, this one is part of the `perl` package:

  ```
  $ dpkg -S /usr/bin/prename
  perl: /usr/bin/prename
  ```
- `/usr/bin/file-rename` : yet another Perl script, no clear authorship information but both a Larry (presumably Wall) and a Robin (presumably Barker) are mentioned. This one is installed by the `rename` package and is also symlinked to `/usr/bin/rename`:

  ```
  $ dpkg -S /usr/bin/file-rename
  rename: /usr/bin/file-rename
  ```

I also have `rename.ul` from `util-linux` but let's ignore that one for now. What is the difference between these 3 Perl scripts? They all seem to have the same man page, `man rename`, `man file-rename` and `man prename` all give me the same page.

I could go through the scripts themselves and try to understand the differences but that is not trivial and I am hoping someone will know what features each has that the others don't.  Bonus points for explaining why the Debian world needs three separate Perl rename scripts.

Comment: It's worse than that! RHEL ships a completely different binary as part of their `util-linux-ng` package. % file =rename /usr/bin/rename: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), ...

Comment: @thrig I converted your answer to a comment since it was not actually answering the question (what's the difference between these scripts and why are there so many perl versions). You're talking about the `rename` from `util-linux` which is `rename.ul` on Debian and `rename` on RedHat systems. I mention it in the penultimate paragraph of my question.

Comment: what does `update-alternatives --display rename` show for you? Wondering if it's part of a post-installed alternative.

Comment: @JeffSchaller no, it comes from [Unicode::Tussle](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::Tussle). Its author (tchrist) is active on SE and he explained it to me in chat.

Comment: Thanks for chasing it down! Too many alternatives in this case -- and causes too much confusion for new users!  Found an interesting search result for Unicode::Tussle -- http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198857/117549

Comment: [Related](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/210286). For the record, the *rename* script with my name on it you mention supports some to-me-useful options like rewriting symlink targets instead of pathnames proper, reading the filename list from pipes, and null-terminated pathnames in that list — plus the  “normal” `-v` and `-i` options. It’s an old, old, old script without proper documentation outside its usage message, but it’s a standard workhorse for *en-masse* filename rewrites. It’s one of maybe two or three scripts that I always want with me no matter where I go.

Comment: [Related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-are-the-different-versions-of-the-rename-command-how-do-i-use-the-perl-ver/730895#730895) too, in depth...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not sure if this should be a comment, but it's only a partial answer -- [Bug#735134: perl: rename(1) is ancient](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/perl-maintainers/2014-February/004113.html) has what seems to be the seeds of the mess. Specifically:

> So to summarise: for many years the perl package has provided
> /usr/bin/rename, a standalone utility implemented in perl. The issue is we don't want to provide the utility from the perl package anymore because it's been added locally inside debian/ and is not being maintained. A maintained version is available as a separate package, libfile-rename-perl.

The `libfile-rename-perl` mentioned above is now replaced by `rename`:

```
$ apt-cache show rename | head
Package: rename
Version: 0.20-3
Installed-Size: 69
Maintainer: Debian Perl Group <pkg-perl-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Replaces: libfile-rename-perl
Provides: libfile-rename-perl
Depends: perl
Conflicts: libfile-rename-perl
Description-en: Perl extension for renaming multiple files
```

So, Perl has its own `rename` which is not maintained by Debian and provides `/usr/bin/prename`. The Debian devs maintain a [`rename`](https://packages.debian.org/hu/sid/rename) package (apparently formerly known as `libfile-rename-perl`) which is the package that provides `/usr/bin/rename`: a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/rename` which itself is a symlink to the `/usr/bin/file-rename` script.

Tom Christiansen's script is bundled with Perl's `Unicode::Tussle` module. You've probably installed it and that's what provided `/usr/local/bin/rename`.