# How can I use the rename command to fix these file names?

Tags: shell, files, regular-expression, rename

I'm trying to change files that look like

`01 Track name.mp3`

into

`01 - Track name.mp3`

So far my futile attempts were

```
rename '0. ' '$&- ' *.mp3
rename 's/0. /$&- /' *.mp3
rename '/0. /' '/$&- /' *.mp3
rename 's/0.\ /$&-\ /' *.mp3
rename 's/0.\ /$1-\ /' *.mp3
```

Comment: `rename -n 's/ / - /' *.mp3` should do it. that will change only the first space to space-dash-space.  test it first with `-n` and if it does what you want run it without `-n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the perl `rename` command:

You're quite close with the last command. `rename 's/(0.) /$1 - /' *.mp3` would work. There's no need to escape the space, they have no special meaning in regular expressions (they do in file names, but that doesn't matter here), and you need parentheses around the part you want to reuse.

Comment: I think my question was a bit misleading; although I didn't mean perl `rename`, that seems to be the easiest way so I installed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to use the `rename` command?

```
$ ls
01 Track name.mp3  02 Track name.mp3  03 Track name.mp3

$ for a in *.mp3
> do
> mv -i "$a" "${a%% *} - ${a#* }"
> done

$ ls
01 - Track name.mp3  02 - Track name.mp3  03 - Track name.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the Perl `rename`, I suppose. Perhaps something like this would work:

```
rename 's/^(\d+) ([^-])/$1 - $2/' [0-9]*.mp3
```

Match anything starting with numbers, then a space, then something other than a dash. Replace with the numbers, a dash, and the next character. (The rest of the name is not touched.) Explicitly checking for the dash here so repeated applications don't end up with files like `01 - - Track name.mp3`.

Actually, your second example seems to work, though of course for names where the first digit is a zero. We could change that to any digits and replace my second captured expression with a negative look-ahead to still aboud adding more than one dash.

```
rename 's/^\d+ (?!-)/$&- /' *.mp3
```

(`(?!pattern)` will match a position that is not followed by the `pattern`, but the match is zero-width, so it doesn't cause a replacement.)

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, maybe because it's a different `rename`. The one I mean is the built in one (util-linux package).

Comment: ah, some of the examples were clearly Perl, so I went with that. You might have Perl rename as `prename`, though?

Comment: I think my question was a bit misleading, but it seems that Perl `rename` is the easiest, so I installed it. Thanks for answering!

Comment: What is actually misleading is that there are two different commands called `rename`. :) But I think the util-linux rename only does fixed patterns, so it's a bit difficult to use here. Of course even without Perl, a simple `sed` command could be used (or the shell string expressions in Stephen's answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ rename 's/^(\d\d)\s*/$1 - /' *.mp3
```

This will rename all MP3 files that has a double digit at the start of their file names, inserting space-dash-space after the digits. So `01 Track name.mp3` will become `01 - Track name.mp3`

Judging from your own attempts, all filenames start with the digit zero, and you appear to want to insert a dash *directly* after the digits followed by a space:

```
$ rename 's/^(0\d)\s*/$1- /' *.mp3
```

This transforms `01 Track name.mp3` to `01- Track name.mp3`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two (three) erase commands: one that's part of the [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) package that's installed on every non-embedded Linux system, and one (two variants actually) based on Perl. See [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames)

The util-linux command is very basic, but you're in the rare situation where it can do what you want. Replace the first space by space-dash-space:

```
rename ' ' ' - ' [0-9][0-9]\ [^-]*
```