# How to create a script or a command line that increment the variable part of the name of my files but some of them?

Tags: command-line, scripting, rename, filenames, variable

I have several files whose names aren't correct:

```
$ ls
devoirNote1_1_2.R  devoirNote1_1_5.R  devoirNote1_4_1.R
devoirNote1_1_3.R  devoirNote1_1.R    devoirNote1.R
devoirNote1_1_4.R  devoirNote1_2_1.R  example140.R
```

I want to change all `devoirNote1_i_j.R` with the i and j integers except `devoirNote1_4_1.R` to `devoirNote1_{i+1}_j.R` (only `devoirNote1_4_1.R` is left unchanged).

I thought of using the command `mv`like `mv devoirNote1_*_2.R devoirNote1_2_2.R` but when several files match (for example if both `devoirNote1_1_2.R` and `devoirNote1_3_2.R` are present), it creates an issue.

**Therefore, how to create a script or a command line that renames my files, by incrementing one of the variables in the filenames, but not all of them?**

Comment: What do you mean with _all_ `devoirNote1_1_2.R` ?

Comment: @ilkkachu you're right, that was unclear, I updated

Comment: Still unclear: there is only one `devoirNote1_1_2.R` with a 1 in the middle. Same for `devoirNote1_2_1.R`. Do you mean  `devoirNote1_1_*` and `devoirNote1_2_*` respectively? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @xhienne I updated with a variable i

Comment: There is only one file whose name matches `devoirNote1_i_2.R`. The way your problem is stated, all you have to do is `mv devoirNote1_1_2.R devoirNote1_2_2.R`. Only one command. Why is it a problem? Why do you need a script for this? Please clarify and provide us with the expected `ls` output after the move(s).

Comment: @xhienne I understand my mistake : I provided a second variable that should make this clearer

Comment: @Marine1 I took the liberty of rephrasing your post. Let us know if this is what you meant. If it's not the case, please feel free to rollback the change.

Comment: By the way how do you decide whch filenames do not need change? Is only `devoirNote1_4_1.R` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Perl's `rename` utility<sup>(*)</sup> can be used for this. It applies a given Perl command to each given filename, and renames the file to whatever it is the commands changed the name to.

So this would change `_1_` to `_2_` on all files the glob matches.

```
rename 's/_1_/_2_/' devoirNote1_*_2.R
```

Incrementing numerically can be done with the `/e` modified to the substitution command, making the replacement part a Perl snippet instead of a literal.

```
rename -v 's/_(\d+)_/"_" . ($1 + 1) . "_"/e' devoirNote1_*_2.R
```

This would pick a part of the filename with digits between underscores, capturing the digits to `$1`, and replace that with the number increased one, with the underscores added back. `-v` for verbose mode. With the list of files in your example, this would print `devoirNote1_1_2.R renamed as devoirNote1_2_2.R` as expected.

The affected files are whatever the glob in the end of the command line matches.

Though note that if you have, say `1_1_2` and `1_2_2`, renaming the first one will fail, since it would collide with the next one. This would require either giving the file names in reverse order, or changing them to some non-colliding form first and then back, say by adding an extra character.

<sup>(* not the util-linux rename tool. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577767/get-the-perl-rename-utility-instead-of-the-built-in-rename) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A script would be overkill for two (batch) moves. Use the `mmv` utility:

```
mmv devoirNote1_2_"*" devoirNote1_3_#1
mmv devoirNote1_1_"*" devoirNote1_2_#1
```

In that order of course. If there are much more than two moves, then a script would be preferable indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Here we make make use of `negative lookaheads` to filter out files `*Note1_3_2.R` and `*Note1_4_2.R` from the search list.

The OP wanted to leave the `*Note1_4_2.R` untouched => we can't touch one previous file as well, viz., the `*Note1_3_2.R`, since we have nowhere to mv this.

The `for` loop logic is there to perform a `reverse numeric sort` on the index number in between the 1 and 2 so that we can perform a nondestructive mv operation.

```
perl -e '
   /(.*)_(\d+)_(.*)/ and
      rename $_, join "_", $1, $2+1, $3 or warn "Could not mv the file <<$_>>\n"
      for
         map  {                  $_->[0]                   }
         sort { $b->[2] <=> $a->[2] || $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
         map  {             [$_, /_(\d+)_(\d+)/]           }
         grep {     /^devoirNote1_(?![34]_1.R)\d+_\d+.R/   }
         <*.R>
'
```