# Remove date and time recursively from filenames

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames, rename

I have a folder which contains folders which contains files of the form

```
resultstatsDF_iris_2017-05-26--21-33-35-437096_methodnr-2_percentage-0.05_seed-0.wcr
```

I want to remove the date and time for each of these, so in this case get

```
resultstatsDF_iris_methodnr-2_percentage-0.05_seed-0.wcr
```

How do I do this in bash?

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` + [`prename`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-prename/) (Perl rename) commands :

```
find yourfolder -type f -name "*.wcr" -exec prename 's/^(.+)_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[^_]+(_.*)$/$1$2/' {} +
```

---

To view `prename` result without action add `-n` option (*print names of files to be renamed, but don't rename*):

```
man rename
```

---

- `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}` - pattern pointing to *date*-like substring (e.g. `2017-05-26`)

Comment: That did not work. How can I say "recursively for my current working directory"?

Comment: @Make42, ok, see my update now

Comment: You linked to the man page of the util-linux rename, but your code uses (one of) the perl rename. The util-linux rename cannot do what you need. The `rename` command is the perl rename only on Debian and derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in ./*/*; do
  j=`echo "$i" | cut -d'_' -f1-2,4-`
  mv "$i" "$j"
done
```

That's not the most elegant solution, but it works just fine, assuming that you want to rename all the files in subsubdirectories and they all match this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it *"with bash"*, then

```
find . -name '*.wcr' -execdir bash -c '
  shopt -s extglob; for f; do echo mv -- "$f" "${f/_+([0-9-])_/_}"; done
' bash {} +
```

This relies on extended glob `+([0-9-])` that matches one or more occurrences of characters in the set `[0-9-]`

You could make the replacement more specific e.g. `${f/_2017+([0-9-])_/_}` if simply matching digits and dashes is too generic.

*Note: remove the* `echo` *once you're certain that it's doing what you want.*

Comment: If you really want to do it “with bash”, you might as well use `**/` instead of `find`. It would be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [perl rename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename) command (either variant, but not the util-linux `rename`):

```
find . -type f -name \*.wcr -exec rename 's/_\d{4}-(\d{2}-){2}-(\d{2}-){3}\d+_/_/' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

If the files are always one directory level deep, then you can iterate over them with something like `for x in */*_20*_*`. Which pattern to use depends on what other files might be present that you don't want to rename. The pattern I just gave assumes that the date starts with `20` and that all files whose name contains `_20` and another undescore after that should be renamed.

You can do the renaming with a shell loop, using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) constructs to build the new file name.

```
for old_name in ./*/*_20_*_*; do
  base=${old_name##*/}        # remove the directory part
  prefix=${base%%_20*}        # remove everything from _20
  suffix=${base#*_20}         # remove everything up to _20
  suffix=${suffix#*_}         # ... then everything before the first remaining _
  mv "$old_name" "${old_name%/*}/${prefix}_${suffix}"
done
```

If the files are at varying depths, in bash ≥4.3, you can run `shopt -s globstar` then `for x in **/*_20*_*; …`. The [pattern `**`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) matches any directory depth if `globstar` is turned on. This also works in bash 4.0–4.2 with the caveat that it also traverses symbolic links to directories. This also works in zsh and ksh, without the caveat, out of the box in zsh and with `set -o globstar` in ksh.