# How to delete one character/letter from file name

Tags: sed, filenames, rename

I am looking to change a batch of filenames to remove a letter, like so:

```
Stain-A_1P.fastq  to Strain-A_1.fastq
Strain-A_2P.fastq  to  Strain-A_2.fastq
```

I have tried the following:

```
rename 's/P//' *fastq
for file in *; do mv "$file" `echo $file | tr 'P' ''` ; done
```

Comment: how did those commands fail?

Comment: `rename 's/P//' *fastq` work for me ... as well as ` rename s/P.fastq/.fastq/ *.fastq` in case there is a **P** in real file.

Comment: linking for awareness only: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `bash` or any other POSIX shell:

```
for f in *.fastq; do ext="${f##*.}"; echo mv -- "$f" "${f%?.*}.${ext}"; done
```

- `for f in *.fastq` iterates over the `.fastq` files
- `ext="${f##*.}"` gets (`${f##*.}`) and saves the extension of the file as variable `ext`
- `${f%?.*}` gets the portion upto the character that follows one character before last `.`
- `mv "$f" "${f%?.*}.${ext}"` does the renaming operation, with appending the extension with the cropped prefix

This is a dry-run; drop `echo` for actual action:

```
for f in *.fastq; do ext="${f##*.}"; mv -- "$f" "${f%?.*}.${ext}"; done
```

---

If you have `rename` (`prename`):

```
rename -n 's{^(./.*).(\..*)}{$1$2}s' ./*.fastq
```

- We are leveraging greedy match with `.*` to match the portion upto last `.`
- The first captured group contains the portion upto the second last character before `.`
- The second captured group contains the portion after the last `.` (including the `.`)

Drop `-n` for actual action:

```
rename 's{^(./.*).(\..*)}{$1$2}s' ./*.fastq
```

---

**Example:**

```
% ls -1d -- *.fastq
Stain-A_1P.fastq
Strain-A_2P.fastq

% for f in *.fastq; do ext="${f##*.}"; echo mv -- "$f" "${f%?.*}.${ext}"; done 
mv -- Stain-A_1P.fastq Stain-A_1.fastq
mv -- Strain-A_2P.fastq Strain-A_2.fastq

% rename -n 's{^(./.*).(\..*)}{$1$2}s' ./*.fastq
rename(./Stain-A_1P.fastq, ./Stain-A_1.fastq)
rename(./Strain-A_2P.fastq, ./Strain-A_2.fastq)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rename` command:

```
for f in *.fastq; do rename 's/P\./\./' "$f" ; done
```

---

- `'s/P\./\./` - *perl* substitution expression: removes `P` followed by `.` (before file extension)

Comment: I afraid this did not work either.

Comment: @AudileF, I'm afraid that you are doing something wrong