# Rename Files Bash Script - Loop Problem

Tags: bash, debian, rename

I am trying to write a script which will take my file and rename *pt-1* to *pt2*
for eg. testfile_pt-1_date.ts at the moment the script will correctly rename to file and copy it to the specified folder correctly.

The problem I have is if there is a file eg. testfile_pt_date.ts, the file is not being renamed but is being copied which is not what I want, I want the file to be ignored, I am not sure why the for do loop is accepting a file with *pt* in it, anyone know where I have gone wrong.

```
#! /bin/bash

file=$1
for file in *_pt-1_*.ts
do
echo "$1"    
a="$(echo $1 | sed s/_pt-1_/_pt2_/)"
cp "$1" "$HOME/SGTV/${a##*/}"
echo "$a"
done
```

Comment: You're doing `file=$1`, but then `$file` is overriden as you're doing `for file in ...`. And in the loop, you're not  using `$file`, but `$1` instead.

Comment: You're also using `cp` and not `mv`, and if your complaint is that it is copying the file, it's because you're explicitly telling it to.

Comment: Yes cp is fine thats what I wanted, what would I use in place of file then in for file in .....? I guess all my variable are a bit mixed up. thanks

Comment: `a="${file/_pt-1_/_pt2_}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a loop, I would suggest you to use the dedicated `rename` tool. It's easier to read, faster to write and avoid confusion.

`rename 's/_pt-1_/_pt2_/' *_pt-1_*.ts`

---

Warning: `rename` is [a mess](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename) on most distributions. If you're using Debian or a derivative, make sure the `rename` package is installed (not just the `rename` binary).

Comment: Thanks, Yes the rename solution works very nicely from a command line. My problem is I need the solution needs wrapped into a bash file as it is called via an external program and is why I am left to try and incorporate the external filename variable $1 into the script.

Comment: Well you can use `$1` as well: `rename 's/_pt-1_/_pt2_/' $1`