# (Bash) Renaming Files Extension

Tags: linux, bash, files, rename

I am having problems trying to create a script to rename all of the files in my directory to `.txt` on Linux.

This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

location_number=$(find /hw1/textarchive | wc -l)
org_path=/hw1/textarchive/!(*txt)
count=0

#for count in $location_number
#do
    # rename $org_path .txt 
    #rename $org_path *.txt
    # mv $org_path  $org_path.txt
#done

for count in $location_path
do
    rename $org_path .pro .txt *.pro  <-----was trying to just rename .pro to .txt (no luck)
done

echo done
```

I tried using `mv` and `rename` but I got nowhere. With the `mv $org_path $org_path.txt` when I run that I would get an error along the lines of `(this file) is not a directory`. With `rename` it would run without any error, but it would not rename any files to `.txt`.

Comment: Please remember to always mention your operating system and, if Linux, the distribution. There are [many different `rename` commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/22222) and each works a little differently.

Comment: @terdon OK got it. Sorry about that. I am using Windows and connecting to my school Linux via an SSH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for name in /hw1/textarchive/*.pro; do
    newname=${name%.pro}.txt
    echo mv "$name" "$newname"
done
```

or shorter,

```
for name in /hw1/textarchive/*.pro; do
    echo mv "$name" "${name%.pro}.txt"
done
```

(remove the `echo` when you are certain it's doing the right thing)

This iterates over all the `.pro` files under `/hw1/textarchive` and renames them to `.txt` files.  The `${name%.pro}` substitution will remove the `.pro` extension from the end of the name in `$name`.

---

If you want to rename *all* files:

```
for name in /hw1/textarchive/*; do
    echo mv "$name" "${name%.*}.txt"
done
```

The `${name%.*}` will remove *any* extension at the end of the name.  Existing `.txt` files will also be processed, but will not have their names changed.  Files without extension will get a new `.txt` extension.  This will also pick up names of non-files (like directories), so the following alteration will skip these:

```
for name in /hw1/textarchive/*; do
    test -f "$name" || continue
    echo mv "$name" "${name%.*}.txt"
done
```

It may be prudent to make sure there's not already a directory entry with the new name too:

```
for name in /hw1/textarchive/*; do
    test -f "$name" || continue
    test -e "${name%.*}.txt" && continue
    echo mv "$name" "${name%.*}.txt"
done
```

On another equivalent form:

```
for name in /hw1/textarchive/*; do
    if [ -f "$name" ] && [ ! -e "${name%.*}.txt" ]; then
        echo mv "$name" "${name%.*}.txt"
    fi
done
```

The `-f` test tests for the existence of the given regular file.  The `-e` test tests for the existence of the given name (no matter what it is a name of).

This solution does not require `bash` (just an `sh`-compatible shell).

Comment: Thx for the info. Two questions 1) in your case do I have to declare `name` as a variable for it to work in the for loop. 2) how would I go about in "adding" .txt to files that do not have any extensions?

Comment: @Paincakes 1) no. 2) see update