# Remove characters from file names recursively

Tags: rename

I have hundreds of directories, some nested in other directories, with tens of thousands of files.  The files need to have a date/time stamp removed from them.

An example filename is `Letter to Client 27May2016~20160531-162719.pdf` and I would like for it to go back to being `Letter to Client 27May2016.pdf`

Another example filename is `ABCDEF~20160531-162719` and I would like for it to go back to being `ABCDEF`.  Note that this file has no extension, unlike the example above.

I need a command that I can run at the root of the affected folders that will recursively go through and find/fix the filenames.

( I use Syncthing to sync files, and restored deleted files by copying them from the `.stversions` directory back to where they were, but found that Syncthing appends that date/time stamp...)

Comment: What OS are you working on? (That can limit the tools available to you)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meet the Perl `rename` tool:

```
$ rename -n -v  's/~[^.]+//' *~*
rename(ABCDEF~20160531-162719, ABCDEF)
rename(Letter to Client 27May2016~20160531-162719.pdf, Letter to Client 27May2016.pdf)
```

([online man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/file-rename.1p.html), also [see this Q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename))

That regex says to match a tilde, as many characters that are not dots, but at least one; and to replace whatever matched with an empty string. Remove the `-n` to actually do the replace. We could change the pattern to `~[-0-9]+` to just replace digits and dashes.

Sorry, you said "recursively", so lets use `find`:

```
$ find -type f -name "*~*" -execdir  rename -n -v  's/~[-0-9]+//' {} +
rename(./ABCDEF~20160531-162719, ./ABCDEF)
rename(./Letter to Client 27May2016~20160531-162719.pdf, ./Letter to Client 27May2016.pdf)
```

Or just with Bash or ksh, though directories with `~` followed by digits will break this:

```
$ shopt -s extglob       # not needed in ksh (as far as I can tell)
$ shopt -s globstar      # 'set -o globstar' in ksh
$ for f in **/*~* ; do 
    g=${f//~+([-0-9])/}; 
    echo mv -- "$f" "$g" 
  done
mv -- ABCDEF~20160531-162719 ABCDEF
mv -- Letter to Client 27May2016~20160531-162719.pdf Letter to Client 27May2016.pdf
```

Again, remove the `echo` to actually do the rename.

Comment: The Debian / Ubuntu man pages for it call it [`prename(1)`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-prename/).  The man page is pretty bare-bones, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes, it's `rename(1p)` in my Debian, and apparently on Ubuntu online manpages too

Answer (score 3):

In bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*~[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*
do
  echo mv -- "$file" "${file/~[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/}"
done
```

This finds all filenames (recursively) that match the date pattern (following a tilde), then echoes a sample `mv` command to rename them. The target of the mv command is the result of a bash parameter expansion that replaces any tilde-datestring text with nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
echo "ABCDEF~20160531-162719" | sed "s/~.*//g"
echo "Letter to Client 27May2016~20160531-162719.pdf" |sed "s/~.*[^.pdf]//g"
```

Above commands achieves the mentioned result