# Is there a way to recursively change filenames from shell?

Tags: mv

Had to do a wget to get files from a Wordpress site. It saved all JPGs with [,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah].

Is there a way to recursively rename these JPGs, stripping all the text after the comma?

Comment: Yes. https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html

Comment: What characters appear in the random string?

Comment: Related: [Batch renaming files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files) & [Recursively rename files and directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18455/recursively-rename-files-and-directories)

Comment: This is even almost exactly the same, just substitute a comma for the tilde: [Remove characters from file names recursively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410257/170373)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python script that should do what you want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
"""remove_extensions.py

Remove meta-data filename extensions added by wget.
"""

import sys
import os
import re

# Define a regular expression to match the file-extension pattern
regex = r'^(.*),random-string-text.pagespeed.blah$'

for current_path, subdirectories, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for filename in files:
        match = re.match(regex, filename)
        if match:
            newname = match.groups()[0]
            newpath = os.path.join(current_path, newname)
            oldpath = os.path.join(current_path, filename)
            os.rename(oldpath, newpath)
```

You'll have to slightly modify the regular expressions to match your actual filename patterns (or update your question to say what they are).

Here is a test illustrating the script in action.

Create some directories:

```bsh
mkdir /tmp/dir1
mkdir /tmp/dir1/dir2
mkdir /tmp/dir3
```

Populate them with some files:

```
touch /tmp/dir1/file{01..03}.jpg,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah
touch /tmp/dir1/dir2/file{04..06}.jpg,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah
touch /tmp/dir3/file{07..10}.jpg,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah
```

Verify what we did:

```
user@host:~$ tree /tmp

/tmp/
├── dir1
│   ├── dir2
│   │   ├── file04.jpg,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah
│   │   ├── file05.jpg,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah
│   │   └── file06.jpg,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah
│   ├── file01.jpg,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah
│   ├── file02.jpg,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah
│   └── file03.jpg,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah
└── dir3
    ├── file07.jpg,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah
    ├── file08.jpg,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah
    ├── file09.jpg,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah
    └── file10.jpg,random-string-text.pagespeed.blah

3 directories, 10 files
```

Now run the script:

```py
python remove_extensions.py /tmp/
```

And finally check that it had the intended effect:

```
user@host:~$ tree /tmp/
/tmp/
├── dir1
│   ├── dir2
│   │   ├── file04.jpg
│   │   ├── file05.jpg
│   │   └── file06.jpg
│   ├── file01.jpg
│   ├── file02.jpg
│   └── file03.jpg
└── dir3
    ├── file07.jpg
    ├── file08.jpg
    ├── file09.jpg
    └── file10.jpg

3 directories, 10 files
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that there's no other comma in the filename, you could try something like this:

```
for i in `find . -type f` ; do mv $i $(echo $i | sed 's/\(.*\),.*/\1/g') ; done
```