# remove first characters if its "0" from all files

Tags: linux, rename, mv

i have  few folder:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

so in each folder i have files like

```
00123.mp3
00133.mp3
00150.mp3
```

so i want to remove all **0** if they are at beginning of filename

i tried this

```
for file in *; do echo mv "$file" "${file//[ ()@0]/}"; done
```

but it remove all **0** in begenning and inside filename (i need just in begining)
also this is not working in subdirectory

Comment: Which shell are you using? bash with shell option `extglob` enabled supports `"${file##+(0)}"` to remove a leading sequence of one or more 0s I think

Comment: Note that it doesn't work in subdirectories because the asterisk wildcard is not recursive - it will always match items in the specified directory only. This is one thing all shells I'm aware of agree on. If you want to go into subdirectories, you need to figure out (and possibly enable) your shell's equivalent of globstar - likely some variation on `**`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bash, this script will do what you ask for:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
while IFS= read -d '' f ; do
    file=${f##*/}
    dir="${f%/*}/"
    echo \
    mv "$dir$file" "$dir${file##+(0)}"
done < <(find . -type f -name '0*.mp3' -print0)
```

comment the `echo \` line to actually perform the `mv` command(s) once you agree with the list of files to move.

Or this sh version for portability:

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -type f -name '0*.mp3' -print |
while IFS= read f; do
    file=${f##*/}
    dir="${f%/*}/"
    f2=$file; until [ "$f2" = "${f2#0}" ]; do f2=${f2#0}; done
    echo \
    mv "$f" "$dir${f2}"
done
```

Comment: Note that `mv` inherits the stdin of the loop, so the pipe from `find`. `-i` would cause it to read the answer to confirmation prompts from the output of `find`. You could read the output of find on another fd (`read <&3... done 3< <(find...`). Or use `mv -i < /dev/tty...`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Can not get the `mv -i` to work, just removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is tagged Linux, you could use `rename` or `prename` command (note that `prename`  is not deprecated, though, but still works). In either case they're perl script for pattern-based renaming.

With group matching and using `*.mp3` glob to pass only `.mp3` files, you can do this:

```
$ prename  -nv 's/(^0*)(.*).mp3/$2.mp3/' *.mp3
Deprecated program in use: rename as shipped with the Debian perl package will be removed after the release of stretch. Please install the separate 'rename' package which will provide the same command.
000004500.mp3 renamed as 4500.mp3
00123.mp3 renamed as 123.mp3
00133.mp3 renamed as 133.mp3
00150.mp3 renamed as 150.mp3
```

Note that `-n` and `-v` are for dry run and verbose output; testing only. Remove `-n` for actual renaming to take effect.

In case you are confused about `rename` vs `prename` , you can read [the corresponding answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/85039) that clears up the confusion, but...I would recommend that you just don't bother with that. Too convoluted :) The point is that in either case it works as shown, unless you're using `ksh` shell.

---

Recursive way to rename files in subfolders would be via `find`, however that requires a bit of acrobatics with substitution pattern to handle preceding items in the file path as provided by `find`.

```
find ./testdir/ -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec  prename  -nv 's/(.*)(\/0*)(.*).mp3/$1\/$3.mp3/' {} \;
```

The above command performed as follows in a test case:

```
$ find ./testdir/ -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec  prename  -nv 's/(.*)(\/0*)(.*).mp3/$1\/$3.mp3/' {} \;  2>/dev/null
./testdir/000004500.mp3 renamed as ./testdir/4500.mp3
./testdir/00150.mp3 renamed as ./testdir/150.mp3
./testdir/00133.mp3 renamed as ./testdir/133.mp3
./testdir/00123.mp3 renamed as ./testdir/123.mp3
```

Minor improvement could be to specify `\d`, the digit class:

```
find ./testdir/ -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec  prename  -nv 's/\/0*(\d*\.mp3)/\/$1/' {} \;
```

Stéphane Chazelas mentioned in the comments possibility where `/0/1.mp3` could be accidentally rename to `.//1.mp3`.  I've taken couple test cases; `./testdir/0/000987.mp3 renamed as ./testdir/0/987.mp3` and `./testdir/007/00123.mp3 renamed as ./testdir/007/123.mp3`  were the results. I think greedy matching of `0*` does the trick.
He also suggested in the comments adding `[^/]` in filename pattern matching. This is a good idea since Unix filenames cannot have backslashes in them; paths can but not individual files. However, I am not quite sure how to better implement this and still have no suggestion on matching `0.mp3` or `000.mp3` types of filenames.

Comment: The recursive one won't work because `^0` will never match because the paths start with `./`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you, I entirely forgot about that. Will try to correct it

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  Edited the answer. Please review.

Comment: There's a risk it could rename things like `./0/1.mp3` to `.//1.mp3` (or `./0.mp3` to `./mp3`, see my answer). You may want something like `s{/0*([0-9][^/]*\.mp3)\z}{$2}` (untested)

Comment: The greedy `.*` at the start will effectively force a match on the rightmost possible position, without it, it would take the leftmost. But I suppose you could sidestep the whole issue of accidentally matching the path by using `-execdir` instead of `-exec`.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '0#(*.mp3)' '$1'
```

(remove `-n` (dry-run) when happy).

The `#` glob operator in `zsh` is like the `*` regular expression operator.

Note that it would rename `0000.mp3` to `.mp3`. To avoid that you can change it do:

```
zmv -n '0#([0-9]*.mp3)' '$1'
```

Recursively:

```
zmv -n '(**/)0#([0-9]*.mp3)' '$1$2'
```

To also remove the `() @` characters as your example suggests you may want to do:

```
zmv -n '(**/)0#([0-9]*.mp3)' '$1${2//[() @]}'
```

(It would however not remove those characters from file names that don't start with a digit).