# Move last part of filename to front

Tags: shell, rename

I have several files named like this: `This is a test - AB12-1998.avi`

(the last code is always 2 letters, 2 numbers, dash, 4 digits)

What I'd like to do is rename them like this: `AB12-1998 - This is a test.avi`

I'd appreciate any solution you can give me using bash, rename, or any other way as long as it gets the job done.

Comment: Are there any files with a `-` in the first part, or is it safe to say ` - ` is a delimiter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the Perl `rename` <sup>(*)</sup>:

```
rename 's/^(.*) - (.*)(\..*)$/$2 - $1$3/' *.avi
```

or, if you want to be stricter about the code:

```
rename 's/^(.*) - ([a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}-\d{4})(\..*)$/$2 - $1$3/' *.avi
```

That should work even with names like `foo - bar - AB12-1234.avi`, since the first `.*` greedily matches up to the final `<space><dash><space>`.

<sub>(* see: [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/170373))</sub>

Or similarly in Bash:

```
for f in *.avi ; do
    if [[ "$f" =~  ^(.*)\ -\ (.*)(\..*)$ ]]; then
        mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]} - ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    fi
done
```

---

Briefly, the regexes break down to

```
^     start of string
( )   capture group
.*    any amount of anything
\.    a literal dot
$     end of string
```

Most regular characters match themselves, though you need to escape spaces with backslashes in Bash (as above). The contents of the capture groups appear in order in `$1`, `$2` etc in Perl, and in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`, `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` etc in Bash.

Comment: Rename is the easiest, but rheck that you have the correct rename (The one written by Larry Wall).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thanks for clarifying, I had to use the bash solution as in archlinux the default rename is a different tool; the one by Larry Wall is called perl-rename.

Comment: @ikkachu I have now my files in this format: "AB12-1998 - This is a test.avi" and have to change them so that the year comes before, e.g. "1998-AB12 - This is a test.avi" - How do I change your bash solution to do that?

Comment: @MarkRoi, Well, it's shouldn't be too hard to modify the above to that. I'd suggest you try it. I added a really short explanation of the special characters I used, and there's a number of resources online about regexes, e.g. [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), even [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Examples)

Comment: @ikkachu Thanks for the extra info. I already tried changing it myself and failed, regex's are really out of my comprehension. I finally managed to do it using awk's substr function.

Comment: @MarkRoi, `(.*)-(.*) - (.*)` should work to split on the dashes, if you can count on the filenames only having those two. Or `(....)-(....) - (.*)` to just nip exactly four characters for the first two blocks. Then just reorder the first two captured groups as above. I didn't test these all through, though.

Answer (score 3):

Using `/bin/sh`:

```
for name in *.avi; do
    n=${name%.avi}    # name without filename extension
    first=${n%% - *}  # first part of name
    last=${n#* - }    # last part of name
    new="$last - $first.avi"  # recombined new name

    printf 'Would move "%s" to "%s"\n' "$name" "$new"
    # mv -- "$name" "$new"
done
```

The `${parameter%%word}` removes the longest suffix string matching `word` from `$parameter`, while `${parameter#word}` removes the shortest prefix string matching `word` from `$parameter`.  The code will therefore swap the two sub-strings on the first occurrence of `-` (space-dash-space).

Remove the commended out `mv` to actually rename files.

---

In comments to [ilkkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444826/116858), I see that you want to swap the first part of the name as well, so that `AB12-1998` becomes `1998-AB12`.

Since we're now doing two swap operations on the name, we can put that into a function:

```
swap () {
    # swaps the two part of a string around
    # the swap point is defined by the first argument

    swstr=$1
    string=$2

    first=${string%%$swstr*}
    last=${string#*$swstr}

    printf '%s%s%s\n' "$last" "$swstr" "$first"
}

for name in *.avi; do
    n=${name%.avi}
    n=$( swap ' - ' "$n" )
    first=${n%% - *}
    first=$( swap '-' "$first" )
    new="$first - ${n#* - }.avi"

    printf 'Would move "%s" to "%s"\n' "$name" "$new"
    # mv -- "$name" "$new"
done
```

Example output:

```
Would move "This is a test - AB9-1995.avi" to "1995-AB9 - This is a test.avi"
Would move "This is a test - AB9-1996.avi" to "1996-AB9 - This is a test.avi"
Would move "This is a test - AB9-1997.avi" to "1997-AB9 - This is a test.avi"
Would move "This is a test - AB9-1998.avi" to "1998-AB9 - This is a test.avi"
Would move "This is a test - AB9-1999.avi" to "1999-AB9 - This is a test.avi"
```