# Batch rename a lot of file using a number find in filename

Tags: find, regular-expression, rename

I have hundred of file name with a number tag in filename like this:

```
AAAA #12 SSSS.TXT
BBB #231 CDF.TXT
CDFSDAAAA #1 AAAASS.TXT
```

and i want to rename so:

```
#012 - AAAA #12 SSSS.TXT
#231 - BBB #231 CDF.TXT
#001 - CDFSDAAAA #1 AAAASS.TXT
```

How I can do it?

Thanks

Comment: Is the "number tag" always the 2nd space-separated portion of the filename, and always following a `#`-mark?

Comment: no, I am unlucky...
maybe the second, the third or more but is ever in the pattern #000 
one #, 1 or more number and a space...

Comment: but it's always some digits following a `#` mark?

Comment: yes
# digit digit digit space
the digit usually are from 1 to 4

Comment: Is it possible that `#` will appear more than once in the filename?

Comment: (probably) my last question: do you have to use `find` here, because they're all in various subdirectories, or are they all in the same directory?

Comment: they are all in the same folder and the # appear one time in every filename...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bash shell,

```
for file in *.TXT
do 
  [[ $file =~ \#([[:digit:]]+) ]] && mv -- "$file" "#$(printf '%03d' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}") - ${file}"
done
```

This loops over all of the files in the current directory that end in `.TXT` and compares them with bash's `=~` conditional expression operator. It compares the incoming filename to the regular expression on the right. The regex looks for a hash mark (escaped, so it's not a comment), followed by some (captured in parenthesis) digits. The `+` is greedy, so it will pick up as much of the number as it can (1 digit, 4 digits, etc), ending at the first non-digit (space, in your case).

Bash saves the captured number in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` (since it was the first set of parenthesis); we send that number to `printf` in order to get it zero-padded to three digits, then append on the `-` for the rest of the rename.

The rename only happens if the match was successful (via the `&&` chaining).

Comment: I strongly recommend using `mv -i` or `-n` when doing any sort of bulk rename like this, to avoid silently & irreversibly deleting files in case of a name conflict.

Comment: absolutely; additional options are to run it on some test files, and/or prepend the `mv` with an `echo` (though you'd have to look carefully to know where the filenames start and end)

Comment: IT WORKS PERFECTLY!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Perl-based `rename` command

```
$ rename -n 's/.*#(\d+).*/sprintf "#%03d - %s", $1, $&/e' *.TXT
rename(AAAA #12 SSSS.TXT, #012 - AAAA #12 SSSS.TXT)
rename(BBB #231 CDF.TXT, #231 - BBB #231 CDF.TXT)
rename(CDFSDAAAA #1 AAAASS.TXT, #001 - CDFSDAAAA #1 AAAASS.TXT)
```

(`-n` added for testing purposes).

Comment: The other solution is more simple, but I will try this one too.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/117549 in case it helps distinguish what `rename` you have...