# Remove Newline from end of Filename

Tags: linux, filenames, rename, newlines

I'm trying to clean up some files on a Linux NAS. They were transferred over from old storage years ago now files and folders include the newline character "\n" at the beginning and end of the file\folder name.

If I look at them "ls -lab" I get something that looks like this:

```
\n Folder_Name \n
```

A similar post helped me remove the "\n" from the beginning of the filename but the one at the end is lingering.

```
(rename $'\n' '' *)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system's `rename` appears to be the util-linux variant<sup>1</sup> - in which case you can just run the same command a second time to remove the second newline ex.:

```
$ ls -Q
"\nfile name\n"
$ rename.ul $'\n' '' *
$ ls -Q
"file name\n"
$ rename.ul $'\n' '' *
$ ls -Q
"file name"
```

<sup>1</sup> see [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename)

Comment: SMH 

I want to promise myself that I did this, but apparently I didn't Thank you!

Comment: @IanYoung n/p - glad to help

Comment: Thanks! thought you might want to see the finished product.

    cd -- "$(find . -name $'*[\n]*' -type d -printf '%h' -quit | grep -v “/.backups”)” ; rename $'\n' '' * ; rename $'\n' '' *

Answer (score 1):

You can just `mv` the file like usual, you just need to put the file name in quotes and hit the return key. So:

```
$ ls -b
  file\n
$ mv "file
> " file
$ ls -b
  file
```

That should do the trick for you, it's worked for me in the past. It would have also worked for the original case, you'd have just need a return before the filename as well.

Welcome to Unix StackExchange!

Comment: I tried that, but the mv command doesn't recognize the file path

mv: cannot stat ‘\FILENAME\\n’: No such file or directory
[1]+  Exit 1                  mv -i "\FILENAME\n" Breaking

Comment: I can manually do one directory at a time when there's only ONE directory 

        mv * NEW_DIRECTORY_NAME 

but if I try any form of entering the directory name as it's listed (\nDIRECTORY_NAME\n) it can't be found

Comment: What's the exact command you typed out?

Comment: ls -b


DIRECTORY\n


mv "DIRECTORY\n" DIRECTORY



mv: cannot stat '\\DIRECTORY\\n' No such file or directory

Comment: @IanYoung Once you open the double-quote, type the filename then hit the return/enter key. It won't recognize the linefeed escape sequence.