# Not able to access files copied using double quote

Tags: linux, shell-script, cp, whitespace

By mistake, I have copied 100 files using the cp command as

```
$ cp file1 "/data/ file1"
$ cp file2 "/data/ file2"
```

note:- there is a space between /data and file2, file1

Within the /data directory, I can see the files but not able to copy or move. File not found the error is while accessing/copy/move those files.

```
$ cd /data/ ; ls
file1 
file2
```

```
$ cp file1 /data1/
can not stat file1
```

How to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The space is now part of the file name, you need to include it in the filename when using `cp` or `mv`:

```
mv " file1" /data1/
```

Or better this, to get rid of that space:

```
mv " file1" /data1/file1
```

---

Do it for all files in one go using Perl rename tool:
(Take care, there are [several different rename tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename))

```
prename -n 's#^ #/data1/#' " file"*
```

(Remove the `-n` if your happy with the result)

Comment: Can we write a script to do the same for 100 files .    while read -r file;
do
mv " $file" "$file"
done <filename.txt

Comment: with files, a `for` loop is usually the better option, but sure you can do it ... See @bxm's answer for an idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#GLOBBINGREF) selection to match the offending files such as:

```
 for f in ./*file?
 do
   echo "[$f]"
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

The space is the problem, you'd need to escape it in references to the files.  To fix all the files in one go (subject to your shell -- works in Bash at least):

```
for FILE in /data1/" "* ; do mv "${FILE}" "${FILE# }" ; done
```