# rename fastq.gz file name

Tags: bash, perl, rename, macos

I have hundreds fast.gz files, and they have the same format of file name:

```
5809029_GWU_DNA_269_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
5809030_GWU_DNA_269_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

How do I change the first and the second underscores to dots? eg:

```
5809029.GWU.DNA_269_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
5809030.GWU.DNA_269_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

without changing the remaining underscores?

I have tried `rename 's/_GWU_DNA/\.GWU\.DNA/' *gz`, it didn't change anything. So I'm thinking about a for loop, any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! I'm trying your command with no issues, it renames the files. You don't need to escape the dots in the substitution.

Comment: I'm using my terminal on MAC, it did nothing.

Comment: do i need to install something?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MAC, I don't know if `rename` is part of the system, or if it is, how it behaves, so I don't know if you have to install something, sorry.

Comment: can i ask- where did you run the command?

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint, bash version `GNU bash, versión 4.4.19(1)`

Comment: macOS does not have a `rename` utility by default, so if you have one, it must have been installed separately.  There are [different variations of this command though](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename).

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a `mv` possibility:

```
for f in *_GWU_*.gz; do 
  mv "$f" "${f/_GWU_/.GWU.}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my question!