# list down files without extensions files on both sides in bash shell but keep original files

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to remove the extensions and prefixes from these files:

```
awstats.www.test1.com.conf
awstats.www.test2.com.conf
awstats.www.test3.com.conf
```

I need to remove `awstats.` and `.conf`, but leave files like `www.test1.com` unchanged. How can I do this?

Comment: Unless there is some other complication, this looks like it would just be a matter of typing in three separate `mv` commands.

Comment: @Kusalananda i need to get keep this file in original location and run the command,i have used basename command but it only remove .conf part.

Comment: @Kusalananda my requirement is list the files exept awstats. and .conf part.also run these values in side the for loop in shell

Comment: Are you aware of the `rename` command?

Comment: @Fiximan i have tried that also, i cant get that remove both sides,this is my command -->  rename -- .conf '' *.conf

Comment: @Fiximan it only remove .conf part according to my knowledge.

Comment: Again, what is stopping you from just doing `mv awstats.www.test1.com.conf www.test1.com`?  I'm trying to figure out what your issue is.

Comment: Your `rename` command looks odd. Please add this to your question in proper formatting. Regexes with two replacements would look like: `s/A/B/;s/1/2/`  ---- @Kusalananda Pretty sure he is working on more than 3 files.

Comment: @Fiximan i have installed AWstats[stats tool] on my linux shared server. after configuration it should add into crontab this command,                                                                                                               0 2 * * * /usr/bin/perl /usr/share/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=tecadmin.net -update  , my shared server have 1000 web site URLs, then its headeche to add those files into crontab. i want to automate this task.

Comment: Please put all corrections into the question. Trying to understand you problem will then be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are in the same directory as your files:

```
for name in awstats.*.conf; do
    basename "${name#awstats.}" .conf
done
```

The code inside the loop will first trim the `awstats.` prefix off from `$name` using a standard parameter substitution, and then lets `basename` trim off the `.conf` suffix.

You could also do it in two steps without calling `basename`:

```
for name in awstats.*.conf; do
    newname=${name#awstats.}  # trim off prefix
    newname=${newname%.conf}  # trim off suffix
    printf '%s\n' "newname"
done
```

No files are renamed by these two loops.

Comment: i want to keep original files if not this service is not working.get the files without extensions and should run pern command in side the shell script.

Comment: @SudeshLakmalPathirana If you have clarifications to your question, please add these to the actual question, not in comments.

Comment: can you give me solution only list the files format.not remove using mv command.

Comment: @SudeshLakmalPathirana I gave you a solution to the issue as stated in your question. Did I miss anything from the question? If you update the question, some of us may update our answers.

Comment: i have updated the title of my question.if that have any doubts please ask without hesitation.and also im new to this community.sorry for the any trouble :)

Comment: when using mv command your script working properly.i want to list files without removing original files.

Comment: @SudeshLakmalPathirana See updated answer. The new code does not rename any files, just prints the modified filenames.  When a question say it wants to modify filenames (you wrote "remove the extensions and prefixes from these files"), people will automatically think it's about _renaming_ files.

Comment: Thank you very much dear.this is what i want.now i want to passed these values into the array and add this command `/usr/bin/perl -config=www.test1.com -update`. i will give it try.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `rename` (`perl-rename` on some systems, just `rename` on others) is simplest here:

```
rename 's/^awstats\.//;s/\.conf$//' awstats.*.conf
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `s/^awstats\.//` substitute `awstats.` at beginning of line (filename) with nothing
- `s/\.conf$//` substitute `.conf` at end of line (filename) with nothing

Use the `-n` option to do a dry-run!

Comment: i just run this command,its not changed anything,thank you for the support.

Comment: Did you use the `-n` option?

Comment: after ran -n option it gives invalid options :'(

Comment: @SudeshLakmalPathirana [There are many `rename` commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename?r=SearchResults&s=1|34.7259), you need the perl one and that might not be called `rename` on your system. What operating system are you using? If Linux, which one?

Comment: @Fiximan note that this will overwrite the existing `www.test1.com` file.

Comment: @terdon im using centos 7.

Comment: @terdon It sure does. I assumed this to be the requirement, but might have misunderstood OP.