# Renaming a file in Bash using regular expressions

Tags: bash, rename

I have a file named `35554842200284685106000166550020003504201637715423.xml` and I simply need to rename it to `42200284685106000166550020003504201637715423.xml` (remove everything before the last 48 characters). This simple regular expression (`.{48}$`) can extract the last 48 characters, but I can't make it work using `rename` in Bash.

How can I use `rename` and this regular expression to rename it to only the last 48 characters?

Edit:

Output of `rename --help`

```
[root@ip-000-00-0-000 tmp]# rename --help

Usage:
 rename [options] <expression> <replacement> <file>...

Rename files.

Options:
 -v, --verbose    explain what is being done
 -s, --symlink    act on the target of symlinks
 -n, --no-act     do not make any changes

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see rename(1).
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you [show us](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/569389/edit) what you've tried, please. It also depends on the version of `rename` you're using - if you type `rename` just by itself what error message does it give you?

Comment: For example, `rename 's/^.*(.{44}\.xml$)/$1/' 3*.xml` works perfectly here

Comment: `rename`s [are legion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/108618). In different distros they may be differently... named. :)

Comment: I'm executing these commands on an AWS EC2 (Amazon Linux AMI) and executing the example sent by @roaima outputs a 'not enough arguments' error. Also, typing rename by itself also outputs 'not enough arguments'.

Comment: Yep, that's the util-linux rename, you are looking for `perl-rename` or `prename`. By the way, [please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Bash used regular expressions for file operations. ???

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't actually need `rename` here, you can work around it:

```
$ file=35554842200284685106000166550020003504201637715423.xml
$ newname=$(sed -E 's/.*(.{48})/\1/'<<<"$file"); 
$ mv -v "$file" "$newname"
renamed '35554842200284685106000166550020003504201637715423.xml' -> '42200284685106000166550020003504201637715423.xml'
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is one using bash specific [P.E.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) parameter expansion.

```
file=35554842200284685106000166550020003504201637715423.xml
```

Only mv for external tools

```
mv -v "$file" "${file:6}"
```

Output

```
renamed '35554842200284685106000166550020003504201637715423.xml' -> '42200284685106000166550020003504201637715423.xml'
```

Keeping the last 48 chars would be.

```
mv -v "$file" "${file:(-48)}"
```

Comment: On my phone so can't test, but would `${file#??????}` be a posix sh compatible alternative?

Comment: @kojiro It is, tested on dash ash, ksh,zsh

Comment: mksh,pdksh. it does not work however on *csh shell variants and fish. The thing is the OP wants to retain the last 48 chars.

Answer (score 9):

Your `rename` seems to be the useless one from `util-linux`.

You'd want to make sure one of the perl-based variants is installed instead (sometimes called `prename`) if you want to use regular expressions. And then:

```
rename -n 's:^\./\d+(?=\d{44}\.xml\Z)::' ./*.xml
```

(here replacing your 48 characters, with 44 digits followed by `.xml` so as to be more specific).

Alternatively, you could use `zsh`'s `zmv`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n '[0-9]##([0-9](#c44).xml)' '$1'
```

Or

```
zmv -n '<->.xml~^?(#c48)' '$f[-48,-1]'
```

(remove `-n` (dry-run) to actually do it).

Which also has the benefit of guarding against conflicts (two files having the same destination name)

With `bash`, you could do something like:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
for f in +([[:digit:]]).xml; do
  ((${#f) <= 48)) || echo mv -i -- "$f" "${f: -48}"
done
```

Comment: I've also seen it called `perl-rename` and `rename-perl`

Answer (score 2):

```
file=35554842200284685106000166550020003504201637715423.xml
rename  "s/"$file"/"${file: -48}"/" *.xml
```

`rename --version`:

```
/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 1.10
```