# Extracting last ten characters of a string (e.g., file name) inside a parameter expansion

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I have a file name (including an extension, but not a full path name)
in variable `file`, and I want to only get the last 10 characters of the base name from a parameter expansion.

Example: `file` contains the filename `A_text_document_1234567890.txt`.

Desired output: `1234567890`.

I know that I can use `${file%.*}` to remove the extension: `echo ${file%.*}` outputs `A_text_document_1234567890`.

If I do `base=${file%.*}`, then I can use `${base: -10}` to get `1234567890`. 
Can I do this inside the parameter expansion all in one step
without using a second variable?

I guess my real question is, how do I combine these two parameter expansions into one?

Comment: You'd better show us the before and after: what is the filename, and what do you want to "pass it"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming a file in Bash using regular expressions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569389/renaming-a-file-in-bash-using-regular-expressions)

Comment: That is `Parameter Expansion` the question is misleading... which has answered on some post here.

Comment: You can't combine them. Take the result of one and apply the other expansion to that

Comment: You can do that in standard shell, without using the non-POSIX `${var:off:len}` form, with `"${file#"${file%??????????}"}"`

Comment: @mosvy, that still doesn't help with removing the extension

Comment: _"I guess my real question is, how do I combine these two parameter expansions into one?"_ -- You don't, not in Bash or ksh, but you can do it in Zsh. See the linked questions.

Comment: @ilkkachu my comment should've probably went below the answer, since it was meant as a portable alternative to `${file: -10}`.

Comment: If the extension of the file is `.txt`, the solution in bash/ksh/zsh is obviously `"${file: -14:10}"` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
file=abcdefghijklm
echo ${file: -10}
```

```
defghijklm
```

The space after the colon is required to differentiate that parameter expansion from the `${var:-default}` variety.

---

Using a 2nd variable:

```bsh
$ tmp=${file%.*}; echo "${tmp:(-10)}"
1234567890
```

Using a regular expression:

```bsh
$ [[ $file =~ (.{10})(\.[^.]*)?$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
1234567890
```

Comment: `${file:(-10)}` will work down to bash2+.