# how to remove string in multiple file name after a specific character?

Tags: filenames, rename

I have multiple file in a folder with this format of name

```
01. file one-sdvanv-12lknl.srt
01. file one-sdvanv-12lknl.mp4
02. file two-afdsmakl-asdfafdaf.srt
02. file two-afdsmakl-asdfafdaf.mp4
03. file three-adfadaasd-asdfadfafad-adad1d1das.srt
03. file three-adfadaasd-asdfadfafad-adad1d1das.mp4
```

Now how to remove the string after `-` so the file name will looks like this

```
01. file one.srt
01. file one.mp4
02. file two.srt
02. file two.mp4
03. file three.srt
03. file three.mp4
```

Comment: Is `file[space-here]` an actual part of filename itself?

Comment: @DevilaN yes they are part of filename itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for file in *; do
    ext=.${file##*.}                #Gets file extension
    [ "$ext" = ".$file" ] && ext="" #If file had no extension, set it to empty string
    nostr=${file%%-*}               #Remove everything after -
    mv "$file" "$nostr$ext"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use bash parameter substitution like this:

```
for i in *; do
  # ${i%%-*} get everything before the first '-' (use ${i%-*} for the last '-')
  # ${i/.*} remove everything after the '.'
  # ${i##${i%.*}} remove everything except everything after the last '.'
  mv "${i}" "${i%%-*}${i##${i%.*}}"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a loop in `bash`:

```bsh
for name in *.mp4 *.srt; do
    mv -i -- "$name" "${name/-*./.}"
done
```

This renames each `.mp4` file and `.srt` file by replacing the part of the name between the first dash and the last dot with a dot, by means of a variable substitution.

I chose to pick out the `.mp4` and `.srt` files specifically, since these are the ones you show in the question.

Using a portable `sh` loop:

```bsh
for name in *.mp4 *.srt; do
    mv -i -- "$name" "${name%%-*}.${name##*.}"
done
```

Here, `${name%%-*}` will be the original name with everything after the first dash cut off, and `${name##*.}` will be the filename suffix after the last dot in the filename.

---

Using the Perl `rename` utility:

```
$ tree
.
|-- 01. file one-sdvanv-12lknl.mp4
|-- 01. file one-sdvanv-12lknl.srt
|-- 02. file two-afdsmakl-asdfafdaf.mp4
|-- 02. file two-afdsmakl-asdfafdaf.srt
|-- 03. file three-adfadaasd-asdfadfafad-adad1d1das.mp4
`-- 03. file three-adfadaasd-asdfadfafad-adad1d1das.srt

0 directory, 6 files
```

```
$ rename 's/-.*\././' -- *.mp4 *.srt
```

```
$ tree
.
|-- 01. file one.mp4
|-- 01. file one.srt
|-- 02. file two.mp4
|-- 02. file two.srt
|-- 03. file three.mp4
`-- 03. file three.srt

0 directory, 6 files
```

The Perl expression `s/-.*\././` is a substitution that will be applied to each given filename, renaming the file.

This substitution replaces the part of the filename from the first dash to the last dot with a dot.

You may want to add `-n` to the invocation of the `rename` utility to first see what would happen.

See also:

- [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename)