# remove repeated names on file names

Tags: filenames, rename

I have many files on my Linux machine with file names like this:

```
Veillonella-sp.-AF13-2-AF13-2.Scaf1.faa
Weissella-cibaria-strain-AM27-24-AM27-24.Scaf1.faa
Streptococcus-salivarius-strain-AF24-6AC-AF24-6AC.Scaf1.faa
```

There is a part of the file name that is repeated. I would like to have only the unique names. 
I want to edit this file name to have only this:

```
Veillonella-sp.-AF13-2.faa
Weissella-cibaria-strain-AM27-24.faa
Streptococcus-salivarius-strain-AF24-6AC.faa
```

Can you please show me a way to edit these file names?

My linux distribution is CentOS

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us i) which Linux distribution you are using (so we can know which `rename` command you have) and ii) add more example file names so we can understand what changes and what is the same.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you insist ona  for loop? That isn't necessarily the best solution. And what does "the names in the file are repeated" mean? What file? How can names be repeated?

Comment: Yes, I dont need to do this by for loop. Somehow a part of the file name is repeated. Such as "Veillonella-sp.-AF13-2-AF13-2.Scaf1.faa" has "AF13-2" repeated twice; Weissella-cibaria-strain-AM27-24-AM27-24.Scaf1.faa has "AM27-24" repeated twice . I would like to remove this from all files.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Perl implementation of `rename`:

```
rename -v 's/(-\w+?-\d+?)\1/$1/' *.faa
```

This would delete any repetition of `-word-digits` in any of the filenames matched by `*.faa` in the current directory.

It does so by by matching `-\w+?-\d+?`, i.e. `-word-digits`, and then that same string again. Such a match would be replaced by just the first instance of the string.

Comment: instructions for installing perl-rename on CentOS: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/centos-111/rename-command-does-not-want-in-cent-os-7-a-4175615551/#post5769407

Answer (score 0):

```
rename 's/-2-AF13-2.Scaf1.//' *.faa
```

Comment: Note that this assumes perl-rename. That's called `perl-rename` on some systems, `prename` on others  and `rename` on still others. [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230)