# Find and replace last char '_' with '.' on filenames recursively

Tags: shell-script, centos

I have some millions of files that have been saved with 'corrupted' name. The extension has been saved as `_pdf`.

What i want is, recursively, edit all those extensions to use dot as expected.

```
find . -name '*_pdf' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1//_/.}"' -- {} \;
```

I have already tried with this bash script but it replaces all '_' founded with '.', i want just the last _ and if proceeded by common extensions (pdf, jpg, jpeg).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's replacing all instances of `_` because `${1//_/.}` is global (`${1/_/.}` would be non-global, but replace the *first* match rather than the last).

Instead you could use POSIX `${1%_*}` and `${1##*_}` to remove the shortest suffix and longest prefix, then rejoin them:

```
find . -name '*_pdf' -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%_*}.${1##*_}"' sh {} \;
```

or

```
find . -name '*_pdf' -type f -exec sh -c 'for f do mv "$f" "${f%_*}.${f##*_}"; done' sh {} +
```

For multiple extensions:

```
find . \( -name '*_pdf' -o -name '*_jpg' -o -name '*_jpeg' \) -type f -exec sh -c '
  for f do mv "$f" "${f%_*}.${f##*_}"; done
' sh {} +
```

I removed the `--` end-of-options delimiter - it shouldn't be necessary here since `find` prefixes the names with `./`.

You may want to add a `-i` option to `mv` if there's risk that both a `file_pdf` and `file.pdf` exist in a given directory and you want to be given a chance not to clobber the exising `file.pdf`.

Comment: worked like a charm. ty

Answer (score 7):

With perl `rename` tool:

```
find ... rename 's/_pdf$/.pdf/' {} +
```

You can run that individually for your different extensions, or replace multiple "common extensions" at once:

```
find ... rename 's/_(pdf|jpg|jpeg)$/.\1/' {} +
```

---

If you don't have perl rename, you can use other [`rename` tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename):

```
find ... rename '_pdf' '.pdf' {} +
```

Comment: thx for your answer, probably is right, but i had to install a tool when i could do it without it.

Comment: At least one of these rename tools is usually included in any distro.

Answer (score 4):

The obligatory `zsh` version:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -v '(**/)(*)_(pdf|jpg|jpeg)(#q.)' '$1$2.$3'
```

(`(#q.)` being to restrict to *regular* files as `find`'s `-type f` does. Change to `(#qD.)` if you also want to rename hidden files or files in hidden directories like `find` does. Replace `-v` with `-n` for a *dry-run*).