# Rename some files with particular format

Tags: linux, bash, rename, mv

I would like to rename some files. I have a lot of files with this format: `?????.pdb`.

The name of this file is composed of 5 characters (numbers and letters) and the new name will be like this `????_biounit?.pdb`. The first 4 characters of the old name must be preserved, while the fifth must be inserted after the word "biounits".

Some examples:

- Original files:

  ```
  1b471.pdb 1caz4.pdb 1ca93.pdb
  ```
- New files:

  ```
  1b47_biounit1.pdb 1caz_biounit4.pdb 1ca9_biounit3.pdb
  ```

I try to do it with the comand mv but I can't tell the difference between the first four characters and the fifth. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 4):

With a shell loop:

```
for f in ?????.pdb; do mv "$f" "${f%?.pdb}_biounit${f#????}"; done
```

- `${f%?.pdb}` removes `?.pdb` from the end of the file name.
- `${f#????}` removes `????` from the beginning of the file name.

Answer (score 3):

Using perl rename tool:

```
rename -n 's/(....)(.)/$1_biounit$2/' ?????.pdb
```

Remove `-n` if you're happy with the output.

Comment: It doesn't work!

Comment: It works, but probably you don't have perl-rename, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename