# How to Rename middle part of multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, centos, rename, command

I have some numeric files like:

```
test01-aaa.txt
test02-bbb.txt
test03-ccc.txt
test04-ddd.txt
```

I need to remove aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd part from the name. what is the best way i can do?
I tried with `'rename'` command, but how can i use this way?

```
rename -v "test??-*.txt" "test??.txt" *.txt
```

to have files like this:

```
test01.txt
test02.txt
test03.txt
test04.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop in the shell (which avoids the fact that [there are several conflicting variants of the `rename` utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230)):

```bsh
for name in test??-*.txt; do
    mv "$name" "${name%%-*}.txt"
done
```

The loop iterates over all names in the current directory matching the given pattern.  For each such name, the end of the string is trimmed from the first `-` using a standard parameter substitution.  The substitution `${variable%%pattern}` removes the longest suffix string matching `pattern` from the value of the `variable` variable.  We then add the `.txt` suffix back onto the result of the substitution.

In the `bash` shell, you may want to set the `nullglob` shell option before running the loop, so that it does not run a single iteration if there is no matching filename.

With `mv` on a GNU system (or any system with `mv` from GNU coreutils), you may use `-b` or `--backup` to back up the destination file if it happens to already exist.  Without `-b`, the above loop would handle name conflicts by simply overwriting the existing file.

Comment: Thank you so much. it works. is it possible to use 'patterns' (test??-*.txt) in rename command? something like this:
rename "test??-*.txt" "test??.txt" *.txt
Is it possible?

Comment: @Sepehrroosta The Perl-based `rename` command takes a Perl expression, for example a substitution command (`s/regular-expression/replacement/`), not shell globbing patterns. With it, you could use `s/-.*/.txt/` as the expression. Since I don't know what `replace` you are using, I opted for not mentioning that command at all and instead use a loop that is guaranteed to work the same regardless of shell and Linux distribution.