# Script which will rename all files in specified by path directory

Tags: shell-script, for

I have to make a script on Ubuntu, which will rename all of files in specified by path directory to be uppercase. I've already found a loop which will rename files, but I'm not sure how I can pass a path to this loop. Can you help me?

Here's the loop:

```
for f in *; do 
    mv "$f" "$f.tmp"; 
    mv "$f.tmp" "`echo $f | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]"`"; 
done
```

I've tried to pass the path like

```
for f in path_to_dir* ...
```

but what it does, it's just somehow making a directory .tmp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you did something like `for f in /path/to/dir*` instead of `/path/to/dir/*`. The former will look for files and directories in `/path/to` whose name starts with `dir` while the latter will iterate over the contents of the direrctory.

In any case, that wouldn't help you because the `tr` command you are using would change *everything*, including `/path/to/dir` to upper case, leaving you with `/PATH/TO/DIR` which doesn't exist. The good news is that you can do it in a much simpler way.

If you're using bash, you can use `${var^^}` to make a variable's contents upper case. So you can just do:

```
for f in /path/to/dir/*; do
    ## get the file's name
    name=$(basename -- "$f")
    ## make the new name
    mv -- "$f" /path/to/dir/"${name^^}"
done
```

Or, to avoid typing out the directory name twice, you could save it in a variable:

```
targetPath="/path/to/dir"
for f in "$targetPath"/*; do
    ## get the file's name
    name=$(basename -- "$f")
    ## make the new name
    mv -- "$f" "$targetPath"/"${name^^}"
done
```

However, this is one of the cases where it is simpler and cleaner to just `cd` into the target directory and work there:

```
targetPath="/path/to/dir"
cd -- "$targetPath" && 
for f in *; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f^^}"
done
```

Or, to avoid ending up in the new directory, run the loop in a subshell:

```
targetPath="/path/to/dir"
( cd -- "$targetPath" && 
for f in *; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f^^}"
done
)
```

Finally, you can also do all this using `perl-rename` (known as `rename` on Ubuntu and installable with `sudo apt install rename`):

```
rename -n 's|([^/]+)$|uc($1)|e' /path/to/dir/*
```

The `-n` makes `rename` just print out what it would do without doing it. If you're satisfied it works, run it again without the `-n` to actually rename the files.

Comment: Recent versions of perl-rename have a `-d, --filename, --nopath, --nofullpath` option that avoids the need to capture the basename explicitly I think? So for example `rename -n --no-path '$_ = uc($_)' /path/to/dir/*`

Comment: @steeldriver ooh, nice! I don't seem to have that on my Arch though, and given [how many different `rename`s there are](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/22222), it might be safer to leave it out.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate you help.

Comment: Using `rename` deserves a separate answer.

Comment: @reinierpost I disagree. I tend to avoid fragmenting answers as it makes things harder to find and noisier.

Answer (score 4):

I'd do something like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
ret=0
autoload zmv
for dir do
  (cd -P -- "$dir" && zmv '*(#qN)' '$f:u') || ret=$?
done
exit "$ret"
```

With that script being called as:

```
that-script /path/to/dir /path/to/other/dir...
```