# Why are neither rename nor mmv working on my Fedora 35 system?

Tags: bash, fedora, terminal, rename, mmv

On my Fedora 35 system neither of the following are working. I have about twenty or so jpg files in a directory, and I wish to add the name of a website to each image after its main title. I am certain that on Linux Mint the rename command worked perfectly, whereas the mmv I downloaded in case there was some problem on Fedora returns a 'no match...Nothing done' error.

```
mmv '*.jpg' '-new-suffix.jpg'
```

or

```
rename 's/\.jpg/-new-suffix.jpg/g' *jpg
```

I have checked the permissions on all files - they are 777 - and the directory itself also has 777 permissions.

I was expecting to see a list of files ending in ...-new-suffix.jpg but nothing has been changed with either of these commands.

Comment: What is the output of `file "$(which rename)"`? I believe the default `rename` executable on RedHat based systems is the `rename` from `util-linux` and that has a completely different syntax, you seem to be expecting `perl-rename`. [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230)

Comment: Output is: /usr/bin/rename: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=2420eb90bf8c8380cc7f4a01b466d1a9e9247d6d, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

Comment: @terdon, though note that the post there explicitly says "I also have rename.ul from util-linux but _let's ignore that one for now._" (I think I've tried to look for the perl rename vs. util-linux rename thing before...)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the replacement marker. Try this instead:

```
mmv '*.jpg' '#1-new-suffix.jpg'
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked perfectly.

Comment: @Hektor that's great. Please remember to accept the best answer with the ✔