# Could you suggest how to use `rename.ul` under Ubuntu 22.04 ? Many thanks?

Tags: util-linux

Could you suggest how to use `rename.ul` under Ubuntu 22.04 ? Many thanks !

```
    Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)
    
     * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
     * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
     * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
    /etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo: 17: cannot create /var/lib/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.cache: Permission denied
    
      System information as of Thu Aug 11 14:43:22 CST 2022
    
      System load:  0.0                 Processes:             15
      Usage of /:   15.8% of 250.98GB   Users logged in:       0
      Memory usage: 0%                  IPv4 address for eth0: 172.25.114.46
      Swap usage:   0%
    
    
    0 updates can be applied immediately.
    
    
    
    This message is shown once a day. To disable it please create the
    /home/user/.hushlogin file.
    user@localhost:~$ rename.ul
    rename.ul: command not found
    user@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install util-linux
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    util-linux is already the newest version (2.37.2-4ubuntu3).
    util-linux set to manually installed.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
    user@localhost:~$ rename
    Command 'rename' not found, but can be installed with:
    sudo apt install rename
    user@localhost:~$ rename.ul
    rename.ul: command not found
    user@localhost:~$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rename.ul` is the version of `rename` installed from the `util-linux` package. If it still existed you would install it with `apt install util-linux`. However, it has been removed from the upstream Debian package version 2.35.2-5 seemingly because of this submitted bug [util-linux: rename.ul is not installed as a possible alternative for the "rename" command](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=926637).

As far as I can ascertain the functionality is available in the command provided in the `rename` package (`apt install rename`), and if you really need `rename.ul` as a command distinct from `rename` then you will have to install it from another source.

Examples of use are given in the documentation (`man rename`). Here is my take, which replaces `abc` with `def` in all file names ending with `.txt`:

```
rename abc def *.txt
```

Also see

- [What's the difference between the different "rename" commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/956010/473234)
- [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/100397)
- [util-linux: rename.ul is not installed as a possible alternative for the "rename" command](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=926637)
- [`man rename.ul`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/util-linux/rename.ul.1.en.html), the obsoleted implementation of `rename`

Comment: But that doesn't work. This is a different `rename` (once upon a time, and maybe you tested that on a system where it is till so) what was called `rename.ul` was installed as `rename`. But on ubuntu 22.04 it is not the case. `rename` command cannot be used as you suggest (it takes a regex and a list of names. So your example wouldn't work. It should be used as `rename s/abc/def/ *.txt`.)

Comment: @chrslg the [official documentation](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/rename.ul.1.html) for 22.04 is that `rename` is as I've described here.

Comment: No. Look at your own link. That is the documentation of the "rename.ul" from Ubuntu 20. The OP is complaining (correctly) about the fact that this doesn't exist in Ubuntu 22. And that `rename` (without UL. Which also existed in Ubuntu 20) is not the same. Try to click on Ubuntu 22 on your own source. You can't. Because that `rename.ul` has been removed. The remaining `rename`, is not working as you described (and that is what bothers the OP. Who knows how to use `rename` but doesn't want to use it that way)

Comment: Apparently, you don't have Ubuntu 22 yourself. I have. I can confirm you that your example would just fail: `Bareword "abc" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at line 1, in:`. And also that `man rename.ul` gives "no entry", while `man rename` shows a man page very different from the one you linked: `rename [...] [ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr [ files ]`. Besides, the removal of rename.ul has outraged more than one person, and it is a very well known fact that this command is no longer available on Ubuntu 22, and that the `rename` of Ubuntu 22 is not the same.

Comment: The Ubuntu package `rename` is the (or "a") Perl-based one [in all versions the package search knows](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rename&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), including 22.04: "jammy (22.04LTS) (perl): Perl extension for renaming multiple files [universe]". The Ubuntu search doesn't show me the package descriptions, but here's the [one from Debian](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/rename): "This package provides both a perl interface for renaming files (File::Rename) and a command line tool 'file-rename' [...]"

Comment: And I think this is manual for the `rename` command from File::Rename, as far as I can find one: https://metacpan.org/dist/File-Rename/view/rename.PL. It has the familiar `rename 'perl code' filenames...` syntax, not the same as the util-linux one.

Comment: So, no, if they want the util-linux one, the `rename` package doesn't seem to be the solution. If the `util-linux` package doesn't install it any more, building the package from source and installing it manually would seem like a way.

Comment: Pending further investigation (and yes I do have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installed) I'd like to delete this answer, but I can't do that. Please bear with me while I take another look

Comment: @roaima, I think the first paragraph is quite right, though.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented in the other answer (of a quite old question, but the correct answer has not been given yet), the `rename` utils, coming from Perl, has not the same usage as previous `rename.ul`

Same final utility sure: rename a bunch of files. But not the same interface.

Perl's rename is used (basically) with a regex and a bunch of files

```bash
./rename s/abc/def/ *.txt
```

for example.

While util-linux is used with an old pattern, a new one, and a bunch of files

```bash
./rename.ul abc def *.txt
```

The perl version is more powerful. You can do way more finely tuned rename with regex. And as a regular user of regex, I should prefer it. But I don't, because util-linux version, in practice, covers 100% of my usage. And works well with readline's tab (most of the time, I want to rename the beginning of a filename), while the perl version forces to be more verbose with the keyboard and type more things explicitly.

They are both pretty old commands. So there isn't a new one and an old one here (surely, one of them is newer than the other. I don't know which. But I've known them for a very long time. Maybe a decade or even more).

Once upon a time, the `util-linux` one was the one installed as `rename` command. And you had to dig for the perl's one.
That is still the case on RedHat for example.
But it has been a long time since it is no longer the case on debian-based systems, for which `rename` command points to the perl version, by default.

But, until Ubuntu 20, the `util-linux` one was available as command `rename.ul`.
It has been removed from debian, and then from Ubuntu 22. This has outraged more than one person, and there are still people posting "bug tickets" in some sort of protest (knowing very well that it is not really a bug, at most a bad decision).

But, well, on Ubuntu 22, you are stuck with only the perl `rename`, and the util-linux is not available, not even under another name (such as `rename.ul`).

For me I use a very simple python script that does the job

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import os

if len(sys.argv)<4:
    print("Usage rename.ul pattern  newPattern file1 file2 file3 ...")
    print("Renames all file1, file2, ... by replacing 'pattern' by 'newPattern' in their filenames")
    sys.exit(1)


for fn in sys.argv[3:]:
    os.rename(fn, fn.replace(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

Of course, it doesn't have the options `rename.ul` had (to control overwriting, dry-run, what to do with symlinks, etc.). Plus, I've never torture tested it with special characters or things like that. But it does what I have been doing with `rename.ul` for a decade. You may use it if you wish (with all the "no warranty" and such disclaimer. If you loose a file because of that script, that's on you, not on me :D)