# Batch rename folders with a single bash command

Tags: bash, command-line, find, mv, gnu

I have folders setup like this:

`/path/to/directory/SLUG_1/SLUG_1 - SLUG_2 - SLUG_3`

SLUG_2 is a year, and it may have a letter after the year, like "1994" or "2003a".

I would like to rename those files to:

`/path/to/directory/SLUG_1/SLUG_2 - SLUG_3`

I'm getting pretty close with this command:

`find $root -mindepth 2 -maxdeth 2 -type d | sed "s#\(\(/path/to/directory/[^/]*/\).* - \([0-9]\{4\}[a-bA-B]\? - .*\)\)#mv "\1" "\2\3"#`

This prints:

`mv "/path/to/directory/SLUG_1/SLUG_1 - SLUG_2 - SLUG_3" "/path/to/directory/SLUG_1/SLUG_2 - SLUG_3"`

Which is exactly the command I want to execute. But I can't execute it.

I tried assigning the output to a variable and executing it by calling the variable. That didn't work. I tried a few variations on that idea, and I got errors.

It feels like I'm missing some tool here. Some iterating tool that makes this job easy. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer, using GNU `find` to handle the renaming.  This method is robust regardless of what characters may be in the filename.

If I understand your use case rightly, you want to rename directories that start with the full name of their parent directory.  In other words, if your directory is named like so:

```
/some/path/abcdefghi/abcdefghi - something - else/
```

You want to rename it like so:

```
/some/path/abcdefghi/something - else/
```

Since you specify GNU as a tag on this question, you can use the GNU extensions to the `find` command and handle this like so:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/([^/]+)/\1[^/]+' -exec sh -c 'new="$(sed -r "s:/([^/]+)/\\1 ?-? ?([^/]+)\$:/\\1/\\2:" <<<$1)"; mv "$1" "$new"' find-sh {} \;
```

Test results:

```
[vagrant@localhost test]$ mkdir -p SLUG_1/SLUG_{1\ -\ SLUG_{2..4}\ -\ SLUG_5,7\ -\ something}
[vagrant@localhost test]$ find . -type d
.
./SLUG_1
./SLUG_1/SLUG_1 - SLUG_2 - SLUG_5
./SLUG_1/SLUG_1 - SLUG_4 - SLUG_5
./SLUG_1/SLUG_1 - SLUG_3 - SLUG_5
./SLUG_1/SLUG_7 - something
[vagrant@localhost test]$ find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/([^/]+)/\1[^/]+' -exec sh -c 'new="$(sed -r "s:/([^/]+)/\\1 ?-? ?([^/]+)\$:/\\1/\\2:" <<<$1)"; mv "$1" "$new"' find-sh {} \;
[vagrant@localhost test]$ find . -type d
.
./SLUG_1
./SLUG_1/SLUG_3 - SLUG_5
./SLUG_1/SLUG_4 - SLUG_5
./SLUG_1/SLUG_2 - SLUG_5
./SLUG_1/SLUG_7 - something
[vagrant@localhost test]$
```

Comment: Can you explain that a little bit? In particular, I don't understand the find-sh {} at the end.

Comment: @JoshuaD, you can read about it in detail here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93331/135943  In short, that string is only used for error reporting by the `sh` shell spawned by `find -exec sh ...`.  I could set it to anything, but I chose `find-sh` to be relatively informative.

Answer (score 2):

> This prints:
>
> ```
> mv ...
> ```
>
> Which is exactly the command I want to execute. But I can't execute it.
>
> I tried assigning the output to a variable and executing it by calling the variable. That didn't work. I tried a few variations on that idea, and I got errors.
>
> It feels like I'm missing some tool here.

**The easy way you are looking for** is to append `| bash` to your command.  That's how you can go from "a command which prints a command" to "actually running the command that was printed."

However, even though you've included double quotes in the command to be printed, **this is a *bad idea* to include in a script.**

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)

You may have handled the whitespace aspect, but what if the filenames include double quote characters directly?  Or newlines?  Or variable names (which will be expanded within double quotes)?

**The *only* characters that are illegal in filenames are a slash (`/`) and a null byte.**

In writing scripts you should hold yourself to a much higher standard of robustness than you might at an interactive command line.

At a command line, you can see the command you are about to run, you can confirm it's correct, and you can then run it.  In a script, there is no oversight and no confirmation.  The script will do what you told it to do, no matter how destructive that may turn out to be.

So the **correct** approach is actually to use `find`, as detailed in my [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318968/135943).  This will handle *any* filenames correctly and doesn't contain arbitrary code execution vulnerabilities.

Comment: Appending `|bash` won't work if there are special characters in file names such as spaces. You can make it work, but it's a lot more complicated than simple `find` usage.

Comment: @Gilles, trust me, *I* know that.  I guess my original answer didn't have enough dire warnings in it, though.  How is it now?

Comment: (Actually, I would love to merge this with my other answer; is there a way to do that or should I just delete my other answer and edit the text from it into this one?)

Comment: Given that the sample names in the question contain spaces, I'd just delete this answer. I'd hardly ever condone piping file names into a shell, but if it's going to fail for the very example in the question, that's a clear no.

Comment: @Gilles, look again.  The OP's command prints a `mv` command *with the needed double quotes.*

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all subdirectories in `/path/to/directory` follow that naming convention:

```
cd /path/to/directory
prename -n 's~/\d{4}[a-z]? - ~/~i' */*
```

`prename` is the [Perl rename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210286/how-to-add-some-characters-to-filename-via-rename/210290#210290) (any of the variants will do).